# Accessing Linux Box from different Windows Host?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, putty, ssh-tunnel

I wanted to access a Linux Box which has on a NAT Network (Virtual Box), the Host OS (Windows having an IP ADDR: 172.16.32.2) and therefore I have done a port forwarding and now able to access the virtual machine using the putty client successfully.

[image: Port Forwarding]

Please look at the above port forwarding rules. I generally access the Linux Machine using Putty Client by entering the IP (127.0.0.1) and Port (2012) on the actual Host (172.16.32.2) where the Guest lives in and it gets connected to the machine successfully.

Now there comes a scenario, where I wanted to access this same virtual machine from another Host (Windows having an IP ADDR: 172.16.32.10). Can we do some SSH tunneling to access the Linux box from another Windows Host? If yes how?

***Note:*** Bridging is an easy option but there is a reason for setting NAT Network. Work environment only has Wireless Network and the wireless interface doesn't always work nicely in Bridged Mode 1. Looking for a solution without modifying the above setup.

1 https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=82339

Comment: So you can't access the linux machine by connecting to 172.16.xx.xx at port 2012? Did you open the port in your firewall settings?

Comment: @SpiderPig, I believe I haven't touched the firewall settings in the windows machine. Could you please guide what needs to be added/modified in the windows firewall settings?

Comment: The can leave the fields "Host IP" and "Guest IP" empty and it will still work since VirtualBox will determine the IP of your Linux VM automatically.

Leaving "Host IP" empty means that it should work for any address - 127.0.0.1 as well as 172.16.32.10.

Try disabling the Windows firewall completely to check if it causes problems.

Comment: @SpiderPig, leaving Host IP makes sense but why "Guest IP" also? What if I have around 10 Guests and how does it know which guests to connect if I leave it blank?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should set-up the port forwarding rule on host machine so that it not only listens to localhost (127.0.0.1) but also on external IP. Then add a rule to your firewall on this host to accept external incoming connections on port 2012.

This should allow you to connect directly using putty from the second host to the 172.16.xx.xx at port 2012.

Comment: Port forwarding is already enabled on the Virtualbox on the Actual Host (172.16.32.2) where the Guest (192.168.2.12) resides. Please look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07bTE.png). Also even in the actual host only this works (127.0.0.1:2012) after the port forwarding and not the actual IP of the host (172.16.32.2:2012) while trying it says "Network Error: Connection Refused"

Comment: Yes I saw this, and what I meant is I think the issue resides in the fact the Host IP mentionned in this configuration is 127.0.0.1 and not the 172.16.x.y. Can you try to change this ?

Comment: Yep tried that, instead of adding 127.0.0.1 as the Host IP in the port forwarding rule, I have added the Host IP (172.16.32.2) and tried connecting the Guest from the Host but it says "Network error: Connection timed out".

Comment: Do I also need to make any firewall changes on the Host side? If yes, could you please detail that information as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes the host firewall needs to accept the incoming connection on port 2012 for the external interface holding  172.16.32.2 IP (this is what I meant in the post above).